NPM error while building a React Native app with expo during the build process
pm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fruntime - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@babel/runtime@7.20.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Got this NPM error while building a react native app with expo during the build process
Tried everything, all the commands available in the Documentations, ChatGPT, but no result. Everything fails.
Tried these:
npm config get registry
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
npm install -g expo  ,
npm cache clean --force
npm install @babel/runtime@^7.20.0
npm config get proxy   ,  
npm install -g npm
npm uninstall
npm install

but still got the same error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/<requirements>
